# SPARQL Query : SR171: Transaction timed out

Tags: sparql

I have been trying to run the following query in SPARQL explorer

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?concept
FROM <http://dbpedia.org>
WHERE {
?x a ?concept
} LIMIT 100
```

When I run it, it gives me

```
SR171: Transaction timed out
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Which SPARQL explorer are we talking about? The DBPedia SPARQL interface? If so, presumably the DBPedia endpoint is currently too busy, overloaded, or even offline. Wait for it come back online or contact its maintainers to find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the website itself. It was under maintenance.

Thanks